# Divide a list of string into groups randomly

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given a list of string of `n` item, I wish to divide it to `b` groups `(b<=n)` where each group has `i to j (j>=i)` items

An example:
Say

```
List<string> lst=new List<string>(new string[]{"a","b","c","d"});
```

(Therefore `n=4`)

Assume the function that provide this functionality is

```
List<List<string>> DivideIntoGroup(List<string> lst, b, i, j)
```

one of the possible result of `DivideIntoGroup(lst, 3, 1, 2)` is

```
{"a"},
{"b","c"},
{"d"}
```

How should I write the DivideIntoGroup functions?

Comment: If `b >= n`, there aren't too many ways to divide the elements into `b` groups :) Did you mean `b <= n`?

Comment: Wrong: `List<string> lst=new List<string>(new string[]{"a","b","c","d"});`

Comment: seems like a homework question.

Comment: Sort the list and select them into groups?

Comment: @xeon111 nope that is not a homework, is a real world problem I face

Comment: Any restriction on `n`, `b`? I mean largest values they can obtain..

Comment: @Boris Strandjev  nope, there is no restriction, but normally n should not larger than 1 million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a C# expert so I will give you a purely mathematical solution, and hopefully you will be able to translate it in your language.

Basically your task consists of two separate parts: choose b groups i to j elements each, and randomness. The second should be easy - just random shuffle the elements initially and then do the group splitting. Lets get down to the interesting part:

How to split n elements in `b` groups containing `i` to `j` elements each?
A straight forward solution will be to take random number between `i`and `j` for the number of elements of the first group, then the second etc. However, there will be no guarantee, that doing so you will not be left with the last group having element number not between `i` and `j`. Also such solution is not doing pure random distribution.

The correct approach will be to get the number of elements of the first group, respecting the probability of solution of the overall group splitting when you take as many elements - you basically are interested how many solutions are overall for the `task(n, b, i, j)` and how many will exist for the `task(n-k, b-1, i, j)` if we assume we take `k` elements in the first group. If we are able to calculate just the number of solutions, you can take each k with its respective probability and do random sampling of k for the first group, then the second and so on...

So now the question is: how many solutions are there for `task(n, b, i, j)`?
Noting the fact that `task(n, b, i, j) = sum(k=i to j) task(n-k, b - 1, i, j)` you can find these numbers easily using recursion (use dynamic optimization, so that you need not calculate the values more than once).

PS: There might be a closed form solution for the number of solutions, but I can't figure it out right away and as long as `n * b` is kept relatively small (< 10^6) recursive solution should work.

**EDIT**
PS2: actually the numbers in `task(n, b, i, j)` might get pretty large very fast, so consider using big integers.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do as a solution is so, this is pseudo code of course:

```
func( n, b, i, j )
{
    if(n == 0)
        return //finished
    if(i>j or i>min(j,n))
        return //no solution possible down this path
    out = choose_random_between (i , min(j,n)) 
    current_ave_of_cells_per_group = ( (n - out) / (b - 1) )
    if current_ave_of_cells_per_group < i
        func ( n, b, i, min(out-1,n) )
    else if current_ave_of_cells_per_group > j
        func ( n, b, out+1, min(j,n) )
    else    
        **form the group consisting of 'out' numbers**
        func ( n-out, b-1, i, min(j,n-out) )
}
```

Comment: This is not going to be evenly random I think.

Comment: it is evenly random as the number is chosen randomly each time, if the number on a certain phase is not possible, it will try choosing a different number which is now bounded into a smaller boundry as to fit more the constraints, the other numbers which are now not possible to be chosen are numbers that cant be chosen to fit this solution no matter what so it doesn't hurt the randomness. this is done until no matter what number he chooses the constraints don't pass.. or more likely untill he finishes putting all his numbers into groups and there are no more numbers

Comment: Your proof is not correct: Consider a case in which i = 1, j = 7, n = 43, b = 7. You will choose the first group of size 1 with probability 1/7, whilst there is just 1 out of 462 solutions starting with first group 1.

Comment: Ok but what you dont understand is that its not only one path, as the recursion goes back up if it fails, therefore if I go with group number one being a size of 7 and carry on choosing 7 it will eventually fail and therefore there will be another chance to pick a group from 1-6. furthermore, you said 462 solutions but didnt mention the total solutions. and as you can see because it is recursion it is incorrect to give a probability to pick the first one and account it for the total probability.

Comment: also now that I think of it, I didn't see him say anything about making it evenly random..

Comment: I am sorry to be a bit bitter in this but: you never backtrack maybe you forgot a `while` somewhere? however, I can not imagine where should you put it so that you accomplish fair randomness..

Comment: I dont need to backtrack if the random number chosen still gives me the chance to carry on to choose the next group..
The pure randomness could be an issue, it needs to pass proofing, but like I said before, he didn't ask for it to be evenly random, he asked for a solution to his problem, and thats what he got

Comment: Thanks for the help, but of course a solution with fair randomness property would be great :)